# Excel usage of intersection operator

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I am very familiar with using the union operator `,` for ranges, such as:

```
=A1,A7
=A1:A6,B1:B3
```

I know there is also the intersection operation   but I have never had any actual use of it. It can be used doing things like `=A:A 2:4` or `=myRange1 myRange2` or `=Table1 3:3`.

I don't think this operator exists in many other spreadsheet programs, such as Google Sheets and some others, though it can be emulated with functions. Is this a practical usage of this operator -- if so, what are some examples of where you have used it in the past? Finally, doesn't the `INDEX` function do what the intersection operator intends to do (and is more common)?

Comment: Maybe I am not familiar with your problem, would you provide more details for example providing a sample data with the input and the expected output for the intersection you wan to do? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once upon a time, Excel would let you specify a range (horizontal or vertical) and its first element was usable as a "Name" for what followed it. So you could do the example approaches you mentioned with no extra work. Then they did away with that, maybe 25 years ago.

Now you'd have to make them actual Named Ranges first and then do it. For anything large-ish, that can be prohibitive, even if you use the `Create from selection` option for making Named Ranges. The reason that is not so useful is that any name it would have to make that violates Excel's rules for naming them just don't get made. And there is no feedback to let you know that occurred... So the very time you would find it useful, with, say 400 rows to name in that manner, if three failed the naming, you would never notice. So that utility is lost now.

It was a compatibility thing as well, with other spreadsheets of the time. That really isn't an issue anymore so not much utility there either.

It will not work on "ad hoc" arrays, as in `={1,2,3} {4;8;2}` and never did, so the utility of that never really did exist.

So nowadays, if wanting to avoid creating all the Named Ranges (like in the 400 row example above), to use it one would have to do lookups for the column and row labels and use the results as the components of the intersection. Those lookups are trivial... if one uses `XMATCH`, not `MATCH` (which fails when using the proper selection of range for the lookup, though if one uses the "obvious" range instead and adds 1 to the result, `MATCH` works nicely too).

Utterly easy to do using something like `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(XMATCH(F7,A1:A5),XMATCH(F6,A1:D1)))` so that can give the utility back if one values it.

So not much here, but maybe some of interest to you.

As far as `INDEX` is concerned, yes, one could use it for this finding elements of a table, though you'd still have to convert column label to column number or index, and the same for rows.

But not everything needs to be ignored simply because `INDEX` can do its work and do it better. For instance, it can do Transpositions and in all four orientations while `TRANSPOSE` can only go back and forth. But no one militates for forgetting `TRANSPOSE`.

Comment: so cool, how long have you been using Excel and how are you so familiar with its history?

Comment: Thank you, You explained very well and save my time.